# Getting the correct data for the form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Currently, I am getting the data from the whole database so I am attempting to filter it and then pass the filtered model to the form so only the data relevant to the user is shown. I did it according to what I found on google but I am getting this error:

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

It makes no sense to me as I am filtering the data as expected. 
Here is my code:

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from posts.models import PDF
from children.models import Children

HEADER_CHOICES = [
    ('Financial Support', 'Financial Support'),
    ('Educational Support', 'Educational Support'),
    ('Governmental Support', 'Governmental Support '),
    ('Charity Support Groups', 'Charity Support Groups'),
    ('Therapy Support', 'Therapy Support '),
    ('Transport Support', 'Transport Support ')
]
AGE_CHOICES = [
    ('0-4', '0-4'),
    ('4-11', '4-11'),
    ('11-18', '11-18'),
    ('18-25', '18-25')
]

class Timeline(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=HEADER_CHOICES)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=AGE_CHOICES)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Children, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Pdf(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='timelinepdfs')
    timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

children model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.urls import reverse
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals

DIAGNOSIS_CHOICES = [
        (1, ("Yes")), 
        (2, ("No"))
]

class Children(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    diagnosis = models.IntegerField(
        choices= DIAGNOSIS_CHOICES,
    )
    disability = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('children-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimelineForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_pdf = PdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form_pdf.is_valid():
            search_result = Timeline.objects.get(
                Q(header = form.data['header']) & Q(age = form.data['age']) & Q(child = form.data['child'])
            )
            form_pdf.instance.timeline = search_result
            form_pdf.save()
            return redirect('timeline')
    else:
        children = Children.objects.filter(parent=request.user)
        tl = Timeline.objects.filter(child=children)
        pdf = Pdf.objects.filter(timeline = tl)
        form = TimelineForm(tl)
        form_pdf = PdfForm(pdf)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {
        'form': form,
        'form_pdf': form_pdf
    })
```

Full error:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/fetz/Desktop/git/majorProjectEXO/parentsubportal/pages/templates/pages/home_page.html, error at line 9
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
1   {% load static %}
2   <html lang="en">
3     <head>
4       <meta charset="utf-8">
5       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
6       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">{% if title %}
7       <title>ParentSuportal - {{title}}</title>
8       {% else %}
9       <title>ParentSuportal</title>
10      {% endif %}
11      <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png">
12      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
13      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
14      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'pages/stylesheet.css' %}"> -->
15      <style>
16      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Righteous&display=swap');
17      #logo {
18        font-family: 'Bree Serif';
19        font-size: 40px;


Internal Server Error: /upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/fetz/Desktop/git/majorProjectEXO/parentsubportal/timeline/views.py", line 40, in upload
    'form_pdf': form_pdf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 986, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 299, in as_p
    errors_on_separate_row=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 197, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 308, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 388, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 658, in value_from_datadict
    return getter(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1247, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Timeline, Pdf

class TimelineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timeline
        fields = ('header', 'age', 'child')

class PdfForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ('pdf',)
```

Comment: Does it tell you a line number? This error usually comes in case of tuples when you pass in more values than you are supposed too.

Comment: @HarshNagarkar it tells me a line number in my home_page.html which makes no sense <title>ParentSuportal</title> shows in red "tle>ParentSupor"

Comment: Could you upload the whole error to the question?

Comment: @HarshNagarkar just did. Sorry still a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that worked:

```
class TimelineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timeline
        fields = ('header', 'age', 'child')


    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['child'].queryset = Children.objects.filter(parent=user)
```

Had to make another form for the correct submission to be passed as I was getting another error.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the stack trace, it seems like the error is coming from some form. My guess would the fields. Change the tuple fields to list. And make sure the fields in the that you are passing are equal to the same that you have in models. I see that you are missing the 'timeline' in PdfForm.

Comment: I have used square brackets for the choice fields

Comment: @Deephousemafia Did it work? After added the field name changing to list.

Comment: my colleague was able to fix the bug he had to overwrite the children field in the form used and the bug was fixed

Comment: Would you please share that share, I am very much interested

Comment: Yes will post sometime soon as an answer to my question